# Unpack ascii string with hex bitmap in jpos

Tags: iso8583, jpos

I have an ISO 8583 ascuu  message with Bitmap Hex.
I tried to unpack it as follows:

```
 String hexMsg="0110E23800018ED006060000000000000011168...M..." 

 byte[] bmsg = ISOUtil.hex2byte(hexMsg);
 ISOMsg mes = new ISOMsg();
 mes.setPackager(new ISO87BPackager()); 
 mes.unpack(bmsg);
```

But I got into trouble because the message was not hex and it contains the character M, for example
I tried to keep the bitmap separate and hex the rest and again the problem was not solved:

can any body help?

Comment: Indeed, it is not an hex string, You can try `hexMsg.getBytes()` but the packager still fails. Maybe you need another packager, starting from one based on `ISO87APackager` or better yet, `GenericPacakger("jar:packager/iso87ascii.xml");.

Comment: @AndrésAlcarraz: It was a good tip